# Windows Forms Open a form that it is inside a folder

Tags: c#, forms, visual-studio

I know if i want to open or jump to another form i need to use the code:

```
this.Hide();
Form f = new Form();
f.Show();
```

But what if the form that i want to open it is on a folder?, [something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gMMod.png)

Im on the Login form and i want to open the Main form that it is inside the "Admin" folder.
Thanks.

Comment: considering that a form is called as a c# object and used. As far as you call the class name (main in this case) and import the right namespace, i don't see why it wouldn't open the form....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each folder in the project will be treated as a namespace so add foldername as namespace and access it

```
using Admin;

Form1 f1 = new Form1();
f1.Show();
```

or simple way

```
Form f = new folder.testing();
f.Show();
```